# How to implement machine learning models on mobile phones?

Tags: android, python, ios, machine-learning

I've built Machine Learning Models Random Forest and XGBOOST on Python or R

How can I implement that my model work in mobile phone IOS / Android? Not for training, just to predict the probability for users by properties and events.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you are applying. You just need to properly capture the data and apply the model.

Comment: if you're using Keras and want to try your model in android, you can try https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/keras-import-overview, for iOS I believe https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml can handle it

Comment: @RishiBansal Can you send some examples or links for reading? thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can expose your `machine learning` model as a `REST API` endpoint. Essentially, the client (mobile) will be making requests at a specific endpoint, which will then be triggering your model.

There quite a few examples available in the Web for you to read but for your convenience you may take a look at this [one](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-machine-learning-model-as-a-rest-api-4a03b865c166).

Comment: I'm thinking about it. But maybe we can push model in sdk or in app. I don't know how. But..

Comment: Ok. But the downside with your suggestion being that your ML will be tied too closely with the mobile OS and you'll also need to maintain both of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm qualified to answer this because it was yesterday that I viewed Google's "DevFestOnAir 2018". There was an "End to End Machine Learning" talk where the speaker mentioned what TensorFlow(TF) has to support AI in mobile devices.

Now, TF is available for JS , Java and many other languages, so this captures the entirety of the model that runs on your PC, uses other functionalities to make it run on lesser RAM and Processors. Do check this out. If I'm not wrong TF has a feature that would do the conversion for you.